# Programmatically using Outlook "voting" functionality

Tags: .net, outlook, voting

Is there a way to programmatically access the "voting" feature of Outlook email? I'd like to be able to send emails with voting enabled, and also get the replies (preferably without polling).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use the [MailItem.VotingOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.votingoptions.aspx) property from the Outlook object model.  For an example, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226712.aspx (scroll down to the section where they talk about the Voting options).